# Initializing multiples super classes python

Tags: python, class

How could I initialize multiples super classes in python..

For example:

```
class A (B, C):
    def __init__(self, param):
        B.__init__(self)
        C.__init__(self, param)
    #
#
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: The code you show works. Of course you know that, because you tried it out instead of using SO as interpreter. So what are you asking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your original code works. It is very clear and readable. The call signature is clear, and allows you to instantiate `A` with either `A(p)` or `A(param=p)`.

```
class A(B, C):
    def __init__(self, param):
        B.__init__(self)
        C.__init__(self, param)
```

It is also possible to use `super`. It offers the appealing ability to replace
the two explicit calls to `B.__init__` and `C.__init__` with one call to
`super(A,self).__init__`:

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print('B')
        super(B,self).__init__(**kwargs)

class C(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print('C')
        self.param=kwargs.pop('param',None)
        super(C,self).__init__(**kwargs)

class A(B, C):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print('A')
        super(A,self).__init__(**kwargs)

a=A(param=1)

# A
# B
# C
```

Using `super`, however, demands a [rather heavy price](http://fuhm.org/super-harmful/):

1. The `__init__` call signatures of all classes
   have to be the same. Since `A` and
   `C` have a `param` argument but `B`
   does not, you have to modify all
   three to use the more ambiguous (but
   uniform!) `**kwargs` argument. Thus, the call signature is no longer explicit.
2. Now `A` can only be instantiated
   with `A(param=p)`, and no longer
   with `A(p)`.
3. Even worse (as Sven Marnach points
   out in the comments), every argument passed to `A` must at some point be popped off of `kwargs` since `object` does not accept any arguments. Once a class
   (such as `C`) pops an argument out
   of `kwargs`, no other class (such as
   `B`) can use the same argument name. So the naming of arguments requires some coordination between all classes, even though ideally, `B` and `C` should be independent of each other.
4. The code has more boiler-plate cruft
   and complication. It's less easy to
   read.

Thus, I generally prefer eschewing `super` (as does your original code) unless the indirection afforded by `super` outweighs the costs mentioned above.

Comment: Nice summary.  I'd like to add that this actually  *is* an inheritance diamond with `object` at its root.  The `super()` call chain will finally call `object.__init__(self, **kwargs)`, so you have to make sure all arguments have been popped off `kwargs` by this time.  This poses a problem in case an argument is needed by two of the classes, and there is no real solution to this problem.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: Thanks for pointing out this additional problem with `super`.

Comment: I wonder why super was called to the language at all, making thing not explicit while not useful for most usecases.

Comment: @dashesy: Here, the base classes have different call signatures. That makes using `super` difficult to use here. If you want to use super, the classes should be designed so the calling and called methods should all have the same signature. If done this way, [super can be considered super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).